# WGET seems not to work with user data on AWS EC2 launch

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I launch an centos AMI I created, and try to add user data as a file which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/centos/testing
cd testing 
wget https://validlink
```

So simply, on launch, the user data creates a folder called `testing` and downloads this `validURL` which I will not put as it links to my data - however it is valid and accessible.

When I launch the instance, the folder `testing` is created successfully, however there is no file inside the directory.

When I ssh into the instance, and run the `wget` command as a `sudo`, the file is downloaded successfully inside the `testing` folder.

Why does the file not get downloaded on the ec2 launch through user data?

Comment: You could use wget flag `--output-file=wget_error.log`  or `wget https://validlink 2> wget_error.log` to catch stderr. Perhaps that will shed some light on the problem. If it is still not clear, consider flags `-v` for "Verbose" and `-d` for "Debug output" and redirect both stderr and stdout to a log `wget https://validlink -v &> wget_output.log`  As a thought, perhaps this command is being executed before your network interface is set up on the machine?

Comment: I assumed the user data is executed once the machine starts on AWS. I will try the output logs now and give you in a update. Thanks

Comment: Ah "User Data" got it now. I was unfamiliar with that term. I agree it sounds unlikely that that it would execute a user data script before the network interface is online.

Comment: So an update, the file does seem to download successfully, however I am unsure about the location of it. So it should be in the testing folder, however it is in this location /test.txt - and it should be in /home/centos/testing

Comment: Since the script is coming in as root, perhaps change that `cd` command to the absolute path or use the `wget` `-o` with the absolute path and filename to write to.

Comment: Please try the curl tool. That is, curl https://validlink

Comment: @JNevill you were correct - fixed the issue. If you write an answer I will accept it

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it working. Looks like @helloV wrote it up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no way of knowing the current working directory when you execute the `cd` command. So specify full path:

```
cd /home/centos/testing
```

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/centos/testing
cd /home/centos/testing 
wget https://validlink
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it using the root user.

Try this instead:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
yum -y install wget
mkdir /home/centos/testing
cd /home/centos/testing 
wget https://validlink
```